# how to share my score in social networking sites in unity3d

Tags: c#

I have developed a game in Unity 3D. I want the user to share their score in social networking sites with their game screen shots. I wrote code in c#. Can any one help me finding the solution please.

Comment: _I wrote code in c#_ You need to show your code first and tell people what have you tried.

Comment: Open this [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/sharing) in that view the image under this heading "Sharing via the Graph API". I am asking like this. I don't no where to star for doing such thing.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook offers a libary for C# to interact with the Facebook API.

Comment: Can you help me how to interact with Facebook API

Comment: Well since I only used one for PHP I cant really help you. But on this site http://facebooksdk.net/ should be all the information you need.

Comment: Open this [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/sharing) in that view the image under this heading "Sharing via the Graph API". I am asking like this. I don't no where to star for doing such thing.